# Why Response.Redirect causes System.Threading.ThreadAbortException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

When I use Response.Redirect(...) to redirect my form to a new page I get the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>       An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

My understanding of this is that the error is being caused by the webserver aborting the remainder of the page the response.redirect was called on.

I know I can add a second parameter to `Response.Redirect` that is called endResponse.  If I set endResponse to True I still get the error but if I set it to False then I do not.  I am pretty sure though that that means the webserver is running the rest of the page I redirected away from.  Which would seem to be inefficient to say the least.  Is there a better way to do this?  Something other than `Response.Redirect` or is there a way to force the old page to stop loading where I will not get a `ThreadAbortException`?

Answer (score 367, accepted):

The correct pattern is to call the Redirect overload with endResponse=false and make a call to tell the IIS pipeline that it should advance directly to the EndRequest stage once you return control:

```
Response.Redirect(url, false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

[This blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tmarq/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect) from Thomas Marquardt provides additional details, including how to handle the special case of redirecting inside an Application_Error handler.

Comment: It executes code after `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();`. Why? Will I have to `return` from the event handler conditionally?

Comment: @Ismail: The old version of Redirect throws a ThreadAbortException to prevent execution of any subsequent code. The newer, preferred version doesn't throw, but you are responsible for returning control early if you have additional code in the handler.

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say "the second overload" rather than `The old version of Redirect` phrase you use in your comment, it's not like MS changed the implementation, it's just another overload.

Comment: I do not think this is an ideal pattern. You are asking the page not to end the response and continue the execution and then completing request programmatically. But what about the rendering of aspx page and event handlers? not ending the response means, it will finish rendering the aspx page before hitting "completeRequest()". Now if I am using a server side property in my page say a session variable to determine valid login, which if expire will throw a null exception before even redirecting. And the only way to fix that is to make the endResponse back to true.

Comment: @Abs I believe your statement "not ending the response means, it will finish rendering the aspx page before hitting 'completeRequest()'" is not correct. According to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#Anchor_0) the page would render after the page load and other control events.

Comment: So adding will CompleteRequest() will "bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event" Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Was going to up vote this answer, but that page code continued to execute. This is not ideal in my case. Much cleaner to handle or ignore the  "ThreadAbortException"

Answer (score 171):

There is **no** simple and elegant solution to the `Redirect` problem in ASP.Net WebForms. You can choose between the **Dirty** solution and the **Tedious** solution

**Dirty**: `Response.Redirect(url)` sends a redirect to the browser, and then throws a `ThreadAbortedException` to terminate the current thread. So no code is executed past the Redirect()-call. Downsides: It is bad practice and have performance implications to kill threads like this. Also, `ThreadAbortedExceptions` will show up in exception logging.

**Tedious**: The recommended way is to call `Response.Redirect(url, false)` and then `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` However, code execution will continue and the rest of the event handlers in the page lifecycle will still be executed. (E.g. if you perform the redirect in Page_Load, not only will the rest of the handler be executed, Page_PreRender and so on will also still be called - the rendered page will just not be sent to the browser. You can avoid the extra processing by e.g. setting a flag on the page, and then let subsequent event handlers check this flag before before doing any processing.

(The documentation to `CompleteRequest` states that it "*Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution*". This can easily be misunderstood. It does bypass further HTTP filters and modules, but it doesn't bypass further events in the  current *page* lifecycle.)

The deeper problem is that WebForms lacks a level of abstraction. When you are in a event handler, you are already in the process of building a page to output. Redirecting in an event handler is ugly because you are terminating a partially generated page in order to generate a different page. MVC does not have this problem since the control flow is separate from rendering views, so you can do a clean redirect by simply returning a `RedirectAction` in the controller, without generating a view.

Comment: I believe the best description of webforms I ever heard was "lie sauce."

Comment: If you use the **dirty** option, You can turn off break on ThreadAbortException in Visual Studio.  **DEBUG > Exceptions...**.  Expand **CLR > System.Threading > Uncheck System.Threading.ThreadAbortException**.

Comment: In my case this exception is not coming for each and every time, only for few times in between it is occuring. Means If and clicking on same button of Live application it is working but when same link and same button is clicked from other machine it is giving System.Threading.ThreadAbortException. Any idea why it not happening everytime??

Comment: If you pass false, and don't bother checking the flag, then the browser will receive the entire page with a 302 status code in the header - found. The malicious user can simply change the status to 200, and gain access to the entire page, which is very insecure.

Comment: If `Context` doesn't resolve for you, try `HttpContext`.

Answer (score 42):

I know I'm late, but I've only ever had this error if my `Response.Redirect` is in a `Try...Catch` block.

Never put a Response.Redirect into a Try...Catch block. It's bad practice

As an alternative to putting the Response.Redirect into the Try...Catch block, I'd break up the method/function into two steps.

1. inside the Try...Catch block performs the requested actions and sets a "result" value to indicate success or failure of the actions.
2. outside of the Try...Catch block does the redirect (or doesn't) depending on what the "result" value is.

*This code is far from perfect and probably should not be copied since I haven't tested it*.

```
public void btnLogin_Click(UserLoginViewModel model)
{
    bool ValidLogin = false; // this is our "result value"
    try
    {
        using (Context Db = new Context)
        {
            User User = new User();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.EmailAddress))
                ValidLogin = false; // no email address was entered
            else
                User = Db.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmailAddress == model.EmailAddress);

            if (User != null && User.PasswordHash == Hashing.CreateHash(model.Password))
                ValidLogin = true; // login succeeded
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex; // something went wrong so throw an error
    }

    if (ValidLogin)
    {
        GenerateCookie(User);
        Response.Redirect("~/Members/Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        // do something to indicate that the login failed.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not have the issue until I wrapped my code in a try, catch... I wonder what other code calls cause this behavior in .NET

Comment: This also will happen inside an if-else statement, not just a try-catch. I believe it's any conditional statement, perhaps even in any event handler. At any rate, performing the change you suggest doesn't do anything to resolve the issue since it's still inside a conditional and an event handler.

Answer (score 9):

`Response.Redirect()` throws an exception to abort the current request.

This [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629) describes this behavior (also for the `Request.End()` and `Server.Transfer()` methods).

For `Response.Redirect()` there exists an overload:

```
Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse)
```

If you pass **endResponse=false**, then the exception is not thrown (but the runtime will continue processing the current request).

If **endResponse=true** (or if the other overload is used), the exception is thrown and the current request will immediately be terminated.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the [official line](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629) on the problem (I couldn't find the latest, but I don't think the situation has changed for later versions of .net)

Comment: @svick Regardless of link rot, link only answers aren't really great answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231 `I think that links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer.`

Answer (score 8):

This is just how `Response.Redirect(url, true)`  works. It throws the `ThreadAbortException` to abort the thread. Just ignore that exception. (I presume it is some global error handler/logger where you see it?)

An interesting related discussion [Is `Response.End()` Considered Harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful).

Comment: Aborting a thread seems like a really heavy handed way to deal with premature end of response. I find it strange that the framework wouldn't prefer to re-use the thread instead of spinning up a new one to take its place.

Answer (score 3):

Also I tried other solution, but some of the code executed after redirect.

```
public static void ResponseRedirect(HttpResponse iResponse, string iUrl)
    {
        ResponseRedirect(iResponse, iUrl, HttpContext.Current);
    }

    public static void ResponseRedirect(HttpResponse iResponse, string iUrl, HttpContext iContext)
    {
        iResponse.Redirect(iUrl, false);

        iContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

        iResponse.BufferOutput = true;
        iResponse.Flush();
        iResponse.Close();
    }
```

So if need to prevent code execution  after redirect

```
try
{
   //other code
   Response.Redirect("")
  // code not to be executed
}
catch(ThreadAbortException){}//do there id nothing here
catch(Exception ex)
{
  //Logging
}
```

Comment: just follow up by the Jorge answer. This will ectually remove the logging of the Thread abort exception.

Comment: When someone ask why he gets an Exception, telling him to just play with try..catch is not an answer. See the accepted answer. I commented on your answer while reviewing "late answer"

Comment: That has the same effect as putting  false for the 2nd argument of Response.Redirect, but the "false" is a nicer solution than capturing the ThreadAbortException.  I don't see that there is ever a good reason to do it this way.

Comment: This fixed my issue where I had an `async` method that although was catching `ThreadAbortException` still remained uncaught. _I ended up adding an extension method to `HttpResponse`._

Answer (score 3):

i even tryed to avoid this, just in case doing the Abort on the thread manually, but i rather leave it with the "CompleteRequest" and move on - my code has return commands after redirects anyway. So this can be done

```
public static void Redirect(string VPathRedirect, global::System.Web.UI.Page Sender)
{
    Sender.Response.Redirect(VPathRedirect, false);
    global::System.Web.UI.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Comment: Maybe *protected method* in  `public class MyBasePage : Page`

Comment: Not `System.Web.UI.HttpContext`. Really `System.Web.HttpContext`

Answer (score 1):

What I do is catch this exception, together with another possible exceptions. Hope this help someone.

```
 catch (ThreadAbortException ex1)
 {
    writeToLog(ex1.Message);
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
     writeToLog(ex.Message);
 }
```

Comment: Better avoid **ThreadAbortException** _exception_ than ***catch and do nothing*** ?

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem too.

Try using `Server.Transfer` instead of `Response.Redirect`

Worked for me.

Comment: Server.Transfer should still be throwing a ThreadAbortException: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629, so it is not a recommended solution.

Comment: Server.Transfer will not send a redirect to the user. It has a different purpose altogether!

Comment: Server.transfer and responce.redirect are different