# Response.Redirect exception

Tags: asp.net

Executing the line:

```
Response.Redirect("Whateva.aspx", true);
```

Results in:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

The exception is because of the "true" part, telling it to end the current request immediately.

Is this how it should be?
If we consider:

- Exceptions are generally considered heavy, and many times the reason for ending the request early is to avoid processing the rest of the page.
- Exceptions show up in performance monitoring, so monitoring the solution will show a false number of exceptions.

Is there an alternative way to achieve the same?

Comment: Similiar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right regarding the fact that the developer should avoid raising of (and catching) exceptions since the execution runtime consumes time and memory in order to gather the information about the particular exception. Instead he (or she) should simply not let them occur (when it's possible).

Regarding the Response.Redirect: this behavior is "by-design" but you might want to use a well-known workaround. Please read [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629).

-- Pavel

Comment: the KB article referenced is now empty.

Comment: @EvoD Not sure I understand, the link works and still points to the right KB article.

Comment: Hrmmm, my mistake. It appears for me now. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

One approach I generally take in this scenario is to not end the response during the response, but to follow it immediately with a `return` (or other flow control).  Something like this:

```
Response.Redirect("Whateva.aspx", false);
return;
```

This depends on where the redirect is taking place in your logic flow, of course.  However you want to handle it is fine.  But the idea is that, when you want to end the response on the redirect anyway, then exiting the method in question via a `return` isn't out of the question.

One approach I've seen people take in this matter quite often, and it should go without saying that this is to be avoided but for completeness I'm going to say it anyway (you never know who may stumble upon this question later via Google, etc.), is to catch and swallow the exception:

```
try
{
    Response.Redirect("Whateva.aspx", true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

This, of course, should *not* be done, for a number of reasons.  As I inferred from your description of exceptions, you undoubtedly already know that this would be bad practice.  But, as I said, it's worth noting this fact in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:
**For Response.End**, call the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest method instead of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the Application_EndRequest event.

For **Response.Redirect**, use an overload, Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse) that passes false for the endResponse parameter to suppress the internal call to Response.End. 

For example:
  **Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false);**

If you use this workaround, the code that follows Response.Redirect is executed.

For Server.Transfer, use the Server.Execute method instead.

from:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us

Same link posted by Volpav.

Regards.