# Unable to evaluate expression

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using a class to check for certain words in my application to prevent SQL Injection.

In the class, there is a for loop that tries to match a specific word with the words from a blacklist.
If there is a match, I must redirect to the system's error page.

However, when a match is found and I try to redirect, I keep getting the error "Unable to evaluate expression."

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CheckInput(ByVal parameter As String)
Try
    Dim errorPage As String = "error_page.aspx?Injection=" & parameter

    For i As Integer = 0 To blackList.Length - 1
        If (parameter.IndexOf(blackList(i), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) Then
            'Handle the discovery of suspicious Sql characters here 
            'generic error page on your site 
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(errorPage)
        End If
    Next

Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
End Try
```

Once the Try block catches the error, it keeps giving the error and doesn't redirect to the error page.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should use prepared statements for sql injection.s

Comment: "Unable to evaluate expression" is from the debugger, not your code. You probably have a watch on some code that is out-of-scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Unable to evaluate expression" is from the Visual Studio debugger, when it sees the [`ThreadAbortException` thrown by `Response.Redirect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception). Without a debugger attached,   your code will work as expected.

[You can pass `false` to prevent the current request being ended](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/) (which is what the `ThreadAbortException` is for). You're then responsible for "ending" the request gracefully.

FWIW, you should also remove the `try/catch`, as it's serving [no useful purpose other than hiding any exceptions](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000352.html). And, as mentioned, SQL parameters are the way to prevent injection - not whitelists.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an infinite loop. Does `CheckInput` run for your error page also?

```
Dim errorPage As String = "error_page.aspx?Injection=" & parameter
```

When you hit an error, you are including the same string that caused the error, thus causing the whole thing to start over again