# Exception from Response.Redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call ASP.NET Function From Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript)
>   [Response.Redirect causes System.Threading.ThreadAbortException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception)

I keep getting an error:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code The thread '' (0x27ee4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I was told it was related to this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Results.aspx?Keywords=" + searchString.Text);  
    }
```

I figured it may help to include my complete code. The code above is the only C# code on my first asp page.

That code relates to this code on this page. It is also the only C# code I have on my second page. I am simply just trying to pass a keyword from a search form to this block of code:

```
if (Request.QueryString["Keywords"] != null){
        string keywords = Request.QueryString["Keywords"];
            string myAppID = "HIDDEN";
            var xml = XDocument.Load("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=" + myAppID + "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=" + keywords + "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=5");
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services";
            var titles = from item in xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "title")
                              select new{
                                  title = xml.Descendants(ns + "title").Select (x => x.Value),
                              };
        foreach (var item in titles){
                Label1.Text += item;
            } 
        }
```

This block of code calls the keyword value and uses it in an api to perform a search. The code of the xml(api) formats like this:

```
<findItemsByKeywordsResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
<searchReslut count="5">
<item>
    <title></title>
</item>
<item>
    <title></title>
</item>
<item>
    <title></title>
</item>
```

Why am I getting this error how do you fix it?

Comment: Do you always get this error? Do you call `Thread.Abort()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Completely normal for a redirect and definitely a dupe.

Comment: You added the tag `asp-classic` but you are talking about `asp.net`. Have you any classic .asp (not .aspx or .cshtml) page related to this?

Comment: @allencoded, apart from the exception, the code in your second page make your site vulnerable to `URL injection attacks.`

Comment: asp.net. and now I never call Thread.Abort() anywhere. What you see is 99% of my code just left out the page loads

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

Comment: tried that didnt work the error went away as I don't get the System Threading stuff. But then my output looks like this { title = System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String] }