# Response.Redirect not working. ThreadAbortException

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect, threadabortexception

I have a problem with a redirect in my code. None of the solutions proposed on the web has worked for me. Basically my code is this (not actual code, only description):

```
protected void btnCool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetDataFromInterface();
    GetDataSpecificDataFromDB();
    SaveDataOnSession();
    Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx", false);
    Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
 }
```

Everything executes nicely, but after the method executes I am just getting thrown to the login page. In the Output windows of VS I see this: *"An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code*."

Here is some extra info:

- I am not using a try catch block.
- I don't have any UpdatePanels on this page, nor in the master page.
- Application_Error does not even trigger.
- **I even have a second button that does almost the same thing (brings other data) and   redirects successfully to another page (same code)**
- I am not changing anything in the Web.Config during the execution.

**Edit:** For clarification. That exception is thrown no matter what. The redirect to the desired page does not work (that mean I have a dead part in my app. I can't get to it.). Instead I'm getting thrown out from the application.

Please, please help me out with this one. I really don't have any more leads that I could follow so any suggestion might be helpful.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception

Comment: I found the problem. It was coming from somewhere else. Thank you for the info. i learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do.

This is by design

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is by default.
The best practice for this situation is mention below

```
protected void btnCool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try{
    GetDataFromInterface();
    GetDataSpecificDataFromDB();
    SaveDataOnSession();
    Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx", false);
    Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
     }
    catch(ThreadAbortException Thrdex)
    {}
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    //Handle exception
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I discovered that the problem was coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I have discovered the problem. It was a classic case of PICNIC. 
That page did not implement an interface that allowed access to a specific type of users. 
Well, at least I learned a lot about redirects and exceptions.

Thank you very much for your interest and answers!!