# login code Redirect do not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made a web application and I want to Login in admincp for adminstrator and modcp for modrator manager.
this is code for login page :

```
protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string user_n = txtUser.Text;
        string pass_n = txtPass.Text;
        Int32 res = 0;


        DAL.DAL log = new DAL.DAL();
        res = log.login_user_form(user_n, pass_n);




        if (res == 1)
        { 

           if (user_n == "admin")
              {
                  Response.Redirect("manage/AdminPage.aspx");
              }
       else 
         {
            Response.Redirect("modcp/defult3.aspx");
        }


        }
        else
        {
            lblRes.Text = "error username or password";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblRes.Text = ex.ToString();
    }


}
```

and in DAL layer this code :

```
public Int32 login_user_form(String username, String password)
{
    int res = 0;
    con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC chek_user '" + username + "' , '" + password + "'", con);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
        {
            res = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            res = 1;
        }

        con.Close();

    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return res;
}
```

and this is my stored procedures :

```
@username nvarchar(50) , @password nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT username_l1 , password_l1 
    FROM user_L1
    WHERE username_l1 = @username AND password_l1 = @password
END
```

this cod in page  login.aspx in work without this line:

```
Response.Redirect("manage/AdminPage.aspx");
```

if I clear this code and write :

```
txtPass.Visible = false;
lblRes.Text = "mesesege";
```

That is work corect but without Response.Redirect, it doesn't?

(I dont know how work whit session for level access)

Comment: Have you considered using the ASP.NET Membership providers instead of rolling your own? http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/membership

Comment: So, if the username is admin, you're not checking the password?  I think I see a security hole.

Comment: Please clarify what it going wrong exactly.

Comment: are you putting admin in txtUser?

Comment: since you are expecting it to be admin in order for the redirect code to execute. what about trying txtUser.text.trim()

Comment: this is code for web.config in manager folder : 
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
and this is code for web.config in root: 

<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms  loginUrl="Login.aspx">     
        </forms>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on Response.Redirect("manage/AdminPage.aspx"); and see if its a hit or miss.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `Response.Redirect()` out of the try/catch since it actually throws an exception.

Even if the code was logically correct, the `Response.Redirects` would be swallowed up by the catch statement.

**Edit:**

This is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception).

Comment: TanX ,I move code out of try/catch this is code : 
        protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  string user_n = txtUser.Text;  string pass_n = txtPass.Text;  Int32 res = 0;   DAL.DAL log = new DAL.DAL();  res = log.login_user_form(user_n, pass_n);   if (res == 1)   {    if (user_n == "admin")   {  Response.Redirect("manage/AdminPage.aspx");}else{  Response.Redirect("modcp/defult3.aspx");}}} 
But yet dosent work :(