# Exception thrown by page redirection in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have this code

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // some code

        con.Open();
        string result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        if (result != string.Empty)
        {
             // some code
             Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

It gives an exception from `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");`

> ex: Thread was being aborted.

any idea why?

thanx

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate question checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirecting from within a Try...Catch statement will result in this Exception being thrown, so this is not what you want to do.

I would update your code to;

```
string result = string.Empty;

try
{
    // some code
    con.Open();
    result =  command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();        
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}

if (result != string.Empty)
{
     // some code
     Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical Exception that is thrown by ASP.NET when performing a redirect.  It's quite well documented on the Interweb.

Try the following catch block to swallow the exception and all should be fine.  It's supposed to do nothing!

```
catch(ThreadAbortException)
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: I would avoid swallowing exceptions - even when in this case there's no obvious side effects, it's a bad habit to get into, IMO.   There are better ways to handle it - for example Tim B James answer below.