# Redirect if Session is Invalid

Tags: asp.net, redirect, session-state, response.redirect

I'm building an asp.net web application that allows users to manage their person account(s) information. Users will have a single web user account, but in some cases it may be associated with multiple accounts at different store locations. So in order for a user to manage their account, I first need them to select the location they want to manage their account for.

This application is a class library that runs within a larger web site, it doesn't define the entire web site. I have a centralized method called GetCurrentStore() that will return the store if a selection exists in Session. If one is not selected, is Response.Redirect([Store Selection Page URL], **true**) the best way to handle getting one? I know this method throws an exception so it is a somewhat expensive mechanism, but I'm not sure I know of any alternatives that will prevent further processing of the response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Response.Redirect causes System.Threading.ThreadAbortException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/why-response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception)

Comment: Pretty similar except I'm asking about a more specific scenario. Given the answer is the same, you're probably right. Unfortunate that the title of that question is a different question than what the user is actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is Response.Redirect([Store Selection Page URL], true) the best way to handle getting one?

"Best" is somewhat subjective and very context-dependent, but some observations:

- By accessing Session from your Class Library, you're increasing coupling (it needs to be called within the context of an HTTP Request, which, among other undesirable traits, makes it less testable).  I'd get the name or id of the current store location in the UI tier, and pass it to the class library.
- If you need to redirect the user to another page, the overhead of throwing an exception is probably negligible.  But again, the class library is probably not the best place to do this: you should check if the current store location is in Session in the UI tier, and do the redirect there.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly.  The primary purpose of using assemblies is organizing code for reuse.  Otherwise everything would just be the main project.  These assemblies shouldn't care about things like session.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense and maybe exposes some flaws, or we might just be talking about a class library in a different sense. This class library spans all tiers. It handles data access to the asp.net membership database and extensions we've added to it, logic such as determining whether to get the current store based on the current url (SharePoint context) or the mentioned session variable, and some web user controls. So I think it is, arguably, in the UI tier? The utility class that accesses the Session variable is the class that puts it in Session to begin with via static methods.

Comment: As far as code reuse goes, that was the purpose here too. We had another user control library (let's call it UCL2) that used to manage and access this same data itself. Things like logging in, getting the current store, and other various tasks around managing account data. Rather than having two copies of similar code, I broke out the account related code into this new assembly and updated UCL2 to reference the new assembly. I suppose the data layer could've been broken out into a separate class library that both user control libraries share, but I don't see the benefit.