# How to redirect category page to first child in Umbraco without a ThreadAbortException

Tags: redirect, umbraco, umbraco6

*(I'm about to answer this question as well, because I've found the solution, but Google didn't really help, so hopefully this will gain some PageRank for the search terms I was using.)*

We have a big Umbraco site with several sections, but most locales don't have section homepages. So if the structure looks like:

```
- Homepage
  - Section1
    - Page1-1
    - Page1-2
  - Section2
    - Page2-1
    - Page2-2
```

and so on, then going to `~/section1/` would redirect you to `~/section1/page1-1/` (and, likewise `~/section2/` redirects you to `~/section2/page2-1/`).

At the moment, we use a macro that checks a property in the locale homepage and then redirects:

```cs
var node = Model.AncestorOrSelf("SiteHome");
var useCSSV2 = node.GetProperty("useCSSV2").Value;
if (useCSSV2 == "1")
{
    Response.Redirect(Model.Children.First().Url);
}
```

We're seeing a bunch of occasions where macros don't load properly, with errors like

> Error loading MacroEngine script (file: PrimaryNavigationSwitcher.cshtml)

displaying instead. Looking at the UmbracoTraceLog, I can see things like:

> 2014-11-25 00:11:28,226 [5] WARN  umbraco.macro - [Thread 39] Error loading MacroEngine script (file: PrimaryNavigationSwitcher.cshtml, Type: ''. Exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>      at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
>      at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
>      at System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread()
>      at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Redirect(String url)
>      at ASP._Page_macroScripts_SecondLevelPageRedirection_cshtml.Execute() in d:\webroot\www.mysite.com\macroScripts\SecondLevelPageRedirection.cshtml:line 8
>      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>      at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.ExecuteRazor(MacroModel macro, INode currentPage)
>      at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.Execute(MacroModel macro, INode currentPage)
>      at umbraco.macro.loadMacroScript(MacroModel macro)
>      at umbraco.macro.renderMacro(Hashtable pageElements, Int32 pageId)

(where line 8 of SecondLevelPageRedirection.cshtml is the Response.Redirect).

That problem and the ThreadAbortException itself are strongly suggesting to me that Response.Redirect is the problem here and I should be using some other means of performing this redirect. (And even if this weren't a problem I'd prefer to avoid the performance impact of a bunch of exceptions being thrown.)

How should we be performing this redirect to have the same effect (so anyone going to `~/section1`/ will be redirected to `~/section1/page1-1/` and so on), without having to add an `umbracoRedirect` or `umbracoInternalRedirectId` to each node and without having these damn ThreadAbortExceptions thrown all the time?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in a handful of places (notably [Why Response.Redirect causes System.Threading.ThreadAbortException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/why-response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception) here on Stack Overflow and [PRB: ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629) on the MSKB), `Response.Redirect(string)` is only present in ASP.Net for backwards compatibility.

To quote from [Joel Fillmore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94204/joel-fillmore) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2777204/205245) to the Stack Overflow question linked above:

> The correct pattern is to call the `Redirect` overload with `endResponse=false` and make a call to tell the IIS pipeline that it should advance directly to the `EndRequest` stage once you return control:
>
> ```cs
> Response.Redirect(url, false);  
> Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
> ```
>
> [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx) from Thomas Marquardt provides additional details, including how to handle the special case of redirecting inside an `Application_Error` handler.

Note that code after the `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` call will execute, so may need handling separately.

Incidentally, as the problem stems from `Response.End`, which includes the code

```cs
InternalSecurityPermissions.ControlThread.Assert();
Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(new HttpApplication.CancelModuleException(false));
```

then `Server.Transfer` will have precisely the same problem. There is more information at [Is `Response.End()` considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful)