# What is the default value of endResponse parameter of Response.Redirect method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to know the default value of endResponse parameter of `HttpResponse.Redirect Method (String, Boolean)` method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default value of `endResponse` parameter of HttpResponse.Redirect is `true`.

Calling Redirect is equivalent to calling Redirect with the second parameter set to true.

Redirect calls End which throws a `ThreadAbortException` exception upon completion. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web application performance. Therefore, it is recommended that instead of this overload you use the `HttpResponse.Redirect(String, Boolean)` overload and pass `false` for the `endResponse` parameter, and then call the `CompleteRequest` method. For more information, see the `End` method.

See this MSDN link for reference - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Appreciate this is an old reply @ManikArora but does this apply for redirecting in an Asp.Net Application_Error handler too? Would you want `endResponse` set to false there too?

Comment: @GavinSutherland, I have not personally used Redirect false, in Application_Error, if you have some operations which you'd like to execute even after the response is redirected then I think it should work for that kind of use case - have a look at this SO answer, he has explained very nicely - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957854/3748701