# Bypass ASP.NET master page rendering after Response.Redirect(url, false)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use my master page's code-behind to display a message to the user after a redirect.  Specifically,

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["redirect_message"] != null)
        {
            // put the message in a hidden field for JavaScript to put in an alert()
            Session.Remove("redirect_message");
        }
    }
}
```

Any page that then wants to show a message can do this:

```
Session["redirect_message"] = "I've sent you to OtherPage.aspx";
Response.Redirect("~/OtherPage.aspx");
```

That works the way I want it to...I first get `OtherPage.aspx`'s `Page_Load` event, then I get the master's `Page_Load` event.  However, I read in many places (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful)) that this way of redirecting is not advisable.  So, I changed to the recommended way:

```
Session["redirect_message"] = "I've sent you (nicely this time) to OtherPage.aspx";
Response.Redirect("~/OtherPage.aspx", false); // don't use Response.End()
Context.Application.CompleteRequest();
```

and unfortunately now my master page's `Page_Load` event is being called *before* `OtherPage.aspx` begins loading.  I see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957854/4062628) response that there's no good way to stop processing the page (other than to use MVC, which isn't an option for me)--is there a way to at least prevent the master page controls from loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach, but it's applicability is somewhat limited and it seems pretty inelegant.  If I can make the decision to redirect in the `Page_PreInit` event, I can replace the master page with another master page that doesn't process the `Session["redirect_message"]` variable:

```
public partial class FirstPage : Page {
    private bool redirected = false;

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (redirect_condition_is_true) {
            Session["redirect_message"] = "I've sent you (nicely this time) to OtherPage.aspx";
            MasterPageFile = "~/Redirect.master";
            Response.Redirect("~/OtherPage.aspx", false); // don't use Response.End()
            Context.Application.CompleteRequest();

        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // for all Page events we're processing, start with:
        if (redirected) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can't just do `MasterPageFile = null`, since the page's elements are looking for a master page.  You have to do this at `PreInit` because that's the last time you can change the master page.  The alternative master page must have all the `ContentPlaceHolder` elements referenced in the page that's initiating the redirect, and it must also specify a `ScriptManager` if the page has a `ScriptManagerProxy`.  Like I said, not terribly elegant...still looking for something better.

***EDIT***

I figured out a better way.  Instead of using the master page's code-behind, I implemented a subclass of `Page` that includes the behavior I'm looking for, then any page that's a redirect target inherits from that subclass.  So:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Session["redirect_message"] != null) {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "redirect_message",
                String.Format("alert('{0}');", (string)Session["redirect_message"]),
                true);
            Session.Remove("redirect_message");
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class OtherPage : BasePage {
    protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        base.Page_Load(sender, e);
        // page-specifc logic here
    }
}
```

then when I redirect, I use:

```
Session["redirect_message"] = "I've sent you (nicely this time) to OtherPage.aspx";
Response.Redirect("~/OtherPage.aspx", false); // don't use Response.End()
Context.Application.CompleteRequest();
```

Having a base class also allows my to put other common functionality in one class.  Comments welcome.