# through exception while redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why debugger going into catch block. What's the issue?? kindly tell me.

exception:"Thread was being aborted".

```
    protected void lnkResponse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Session["idTicket"] = hfIdTicket.Value;

            Response.Redirect("~/Forms/TicketChat.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know if you don't even tell us what kind of Exception you get?

Comment: What is the exact exception?

Comment: please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2777105/492258) Response.Redirect causes exception

Comment: There might be something wrong with hfIdTicket.Value;

Comment: no hfIdTicket.Value having value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Response.Redirect causes System.Threading.ThreadAbortException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/why-response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception)

Comment: add false - Response.Redirect("~/Forms/TicketChat.aspx",false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Response.Redirect` throws the `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException` exception.

Try using an overload, `Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse)` that passes `false` for the `endResponse` parameter to suppress the internal call to `Response.End`.

```
Response.Redirect ("~/Forms/TicketChat.aspx", false);
```