# IIS Application auto logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, iis

In Windows Server 2012, I have IIS 8 installed. For one IIS application, I am using an application pool. I try to increase the Maximum Worker Processes to 10, however, when I open the website in a browser, it will auto log out when I click any link. When I change back the Maximum Worker Processes to 1. The log out will not happen. But in another server, the same website with Maximum Worker Processes 16, the auto log out will not happen. Why the maximum worker processes will cause the website to auto log out? I checked the error log and found that there was ThreadAbortException which is happened when Response.Redirect is run.

Comment: I think this link can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/why-response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception

Answer (score 0):

It could be the ASP.NET session state is not being stored out-of-process. Please check these two articles:

http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/07/23/163356.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

This setting seems to be in the web.config, so you can compare the two web.config files to see if there is any difference.